# Animation with jquery, moving letler

Tags: jquery, animation, sequence

I am trying to create animation of letter, which on click will be moving up and shaking in the same time, and the end will disappear and show up in the middle of the screen covering 80% of a page. I managed to make it move up, but I am hopeless to make it shake, disappear and show up again.

```
I want it to:
1.moving up ,
2.turn left 10 degree ,
3.turn right 10 degree ,
4.turn left 10 degree ,
5.turn right 10 degree ,
6.fade ,
7.cover in shadow whole page ,
8.show letter in the middle of the page
```

Code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.envelope').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('.list').addClass('listani');
    });

    $(".envelope").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find('.list').removeClass('listani');
    });

    $('.envelope').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.list')
          .toggleClass("listmove");
    });

});
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/eH6Xc/)

Comment: Look into [jQuery UI Effect](http://jqueryui.com/effect/).

Comment: thanks, but is is to complicate for me. Could you tell me how it should to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you can do all the effects you want using this. E.g. `$('.element').animate({left: '+=10'}, 300);`

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for effect like rotation(10deg) in CSS.

Comment: **Something like this:**
`@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(10deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(10deg);}
}`
**And then you can use:**
`.blah {
-moz-animation: spin;
-o-animation: spin;
-webkit-animation: spin;
animation: spin;
}`
**And add or remove classes like desired.**